# The distribution of $h\circ \Phi$ where $\Phi$ has p.d.f. $\frac12\sin\phi$ and $h(\phi)=a\cos\phi+b$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification

I would be really grateful if someone could check what I have done here; it should be quick:

> Let $\Phi$ be a random variable taking values in $[0,\pi]$ with PDF
>   $f(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\phi$. Define: $$h(\phi)=a\cos(\phi)+b$$ where $a,b$
>   are positive constants. I need to find the distribution of $h(\Phi)$.

**Attempt:**

The PDF of $h(\Phi)$ should be: $$f(h^{-1}(\phi))\cdot \frac{d}{d\phi}h^{-1}(\phi)$$
I get this to be the constant $-1/(2a)$, so $h(\Phi)$ has uniform distribution. In particular

$$h(\Phi)\sim \mathcal{U}\left(b-a,b+a\right)$$

Can I check that this is correct?

Comment: Correct. Pretty nifty result, eh?

Comment: @Did Yes! And thank you for replying so quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation is correct. I will add that this is an instance of a more general fact: if $\Phi$ is a random variable with continuous CDF $g$, then $g\circ \Phi$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/868400)).

In your case, the CDF of $\phi$ is $\frac12(1-\cos\phi)$, so applying this function to $\Phi$ produces a variable $\sim U(0,1)$. And $a\cos\phi+b$ is just a linear transformation of $\frac12(1-\cos\phi)$, scaling and adding a constant. More precisely, it is  the transformation $x\mapsto -2a x+(a+b)$, hence the interval $[0,1]$ is mapped to $[b-a, b+a]$.