# Function of random variable has uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For any random variable $X$ taking values in $[0,1]$ with distribution $\mu_X$, and $f$ defined by $f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t d\mu_X$, I'm stuck trying to show that 
$$P(f(X) \leq a) = a$$
for all $a \in [0,1]$. I don't really have any work to show. I've tried rewriting things using integrals, but it hasn't gotten me anywhere. Even just a hint would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is $f(X)$?  Is it $P(X≤X)$?  that would seem to be $1$.  Is $f(X)$ somehow meant to be a random variable?

Comment: If $a=39$ your expression would appear to give a probability equal to $39$.  Just for example.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, edited

Comment: Much better, but I still don't get it.  If $a=0$ your expression would appear to suggest that the probability that $X≤0$ is $0$, but that need not be true.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, edited again.

Comment: Ah, now I believe it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing that Y has a uniform distribution if Y=F(X) where F is the cdf of continuous X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868400/showing-that-y-has-a-uniform-distribution-if-y-fx-where-f-is-the-cdf-of-contin)

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ is the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF) of $X$, defined by $t \mapsto \mathbb{P}(X\leq t)$. By definition, $f$ is increasing. Moreover, if $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing,
then
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(f(X)\leq a ) & = \mathbb{P}(X\leq f^{-1}(a) ) \\ & = f(f^{-1}(a))\\ & = a
\end{aligned}
for $a$ is in $[0,1]$. If there is a single subdomain $]x_\mathit{inf},x_\mathit{sup}[$ of $\mathbb{R}$ on which $f$ is constant, then
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(f(X)\leq a ) &= {\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{P}(X\leq f^{-1}(a) ) && \text{if} \quad a < f (x_\mathit{sup}) \\
&\mathbb{P}(X\leq x_\mathit{sup} ) && \text{if} \quad a = f (x_\mathit{sup}) \\
&\mathbb{P}(X\leq f^{-1}(a) ) && \text{if} \quad f (x_\mathit{sup}) < a \, .
\end{aligned}\right.} \\
&= a \, .
\end{aligned}
Therefore, the property still holds. Now let us assume that $f$ has a single discontinuity at the abscissa $x_0$. If the jump in $f$ is of height $f (x_0^+) - f (x_0^-)$, then
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(f(X)\leq a ) &= {\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{P}(X\leq f^{-1}(a) ) && \text{if} \quad a < f (x_0^-) \\
&\mathbb{P}(X\leq x_0 ) && \text{if} \quad f (x_0^-) \leq a <   f (x_0^+) \\
&\mathbb{P}(X\leq f^{-1}(a) ) && \text{if} \quad f (x_0^+) \leq a
\end{aligned}\right.} \\
&= {\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
&f (x_0^-) && \text{if} \quad f (x_0^-) \leq a <   f (x_0^+) \\
&a && \text{otherwise} \, .
\end{aligned}\right.}
\end{aligned}
In this case, the property is no longer true.

To summarize, if the CDF $f$ is continuous, i.e. X is a continuous random variable, then $f(X)$ has a uniform distribution.

Comment: What if $f$ is not strictly increasing?

Comment: Why is $P(f(X) \leq a) = P(X \leq x_\sup)$ if $a = f(x_\sup)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is strictly increasing, then Harry49's answer works just fine. If not, this is no longer true. Take the simple example where $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=\frac12$. Then $f(x)=\frac12$ for $0\le x<1$ and $f(1)=1$. Take $a=\frac14$. Then $P(f(X)\le a)=0\neq a$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.