# Given the cumulative distribution function find a random variable that has this distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

We are given a Cumulative distribution function $(CDF)$ how do we find a random variable that has the given distribution? Since there could be a lot of such variables we are to find anyone given that the function is differentiable and increasing.

I read somewhere that we could simply take inverse of the function(if it exists) and that would be the Random variable you are looking for, but I don't understand it, even if it's true(?).

If that's true, why? Else, how do we find a random variable for the distribution?

Comment: I see that the answers discuss prob integral transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform), which answers/clarifies the second paragraph of the question of generating a rv $X$ that has the given CDF from a standard uniform rv. But I don't know what the question in the title `given the cumulative distribution function find a random variable that has this distribution` means since if a cdf $F(x)$ is given for some random variable $X$ then for any $a$ and $b$ the probability $P(a < X \leq b)$ is nailed down by $F(b)-F(a)$ so $F(x)$ does indeed specify the rv a.e.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer Obviously F(x) is a random variable, but it's distribution isn't the same as F(x).

Comment: $F(x)$ by convention is not a random variable. It is a real valued function $\mathbb R \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by $F(x) = P(X \leq x)$. So my point is specifying $F(x)$ is a.e. same as specifying $X$.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer I don't understand your point, even if $F(x)$ is a r.v. how does it help in finding a r.v. whose CDF is $F(x)$. Since CDF of the r.v. $F(x)$ is not necessarily $F(x)$.

Comment: Let me try it differently. You give me a valid CDF $F(x)$ and say this is the CDF of some rv $X$. Using just that $F(x)$ and nothing else, I can compute any probabilities, moments, etc.etc. involving the rv $X$.

Comment: To boot, if $F(x)$ is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb R$, then fundamental theorem of calculus says $F'(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer that would give me pdf of X and not a random variable whose distribution is given by the given cdf.

Comment: I guess the confusion is related to the language. In the title, perhaps the word "find" should be replaced by "generate" or "create" or something like that. To me, if someone says to "find" a rv $X$ which satisfies certain properties and if I provide the CDF, I am done. For example, to *find* a rv $Y$ with constant failure rate of 2, it is sufficient to say take $Y$ with CDF $1-\exp (-2y)$. With that in mind, to me, starting with $F(x)$ and asking to "find" the rv whose distribution is given by $F(x)$, is like asking "who's on first".

Comment: ahh @Just_to_Answer I get it, I want the function $X$ and not it's distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are studying elementary probability theory, allow me to reformulate your question as "how can I represent a random variable $X$ with a given CDF $F_X$ in terms of a uniform random variable $U$ on $(0,1)$?" The answer to that is the quantile function: you define

$$G_X(p)=\inf \{ x : F_X(x) \geq p \}$$
and then define $X$ to be $G_X(U)$.

Note that if $F_X$ is invertible then $G_X=F_X^{-1}$, otherwise this is "the right generalization". One can see this by looking at the discrete case: if $P(X=x)=p$ then $P(G_X(U)=x)=p$. This is because a jump of height $p$ in $F_X$ corresponds to a flat region of length $p$ in $G_X$, and the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ assigns each interval a probability equal to its length.

The natural question is now "what's a uniform random variable on $(0,1)$?" Well, it has $F_U(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ x & x \in [0,1] \\ 1 & x>1 \end{cases}$. But otherwise such a thing is a black box from the elementary point of view.

If you are studying measure-theoretic probability theory then the answer is a bit more explicit. A random variable with CDF $F_X$ is given by $G_X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ where $G_X$ is the quantile function as defined before, $\Omega=(0,1)$, $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(0,1)$, and $\mathbb{P}$ is the Lebesgue measure. Note that on this space the identity function is a uniform random variable on $(0,1)$, so this is really the same construction as the one described above.

In any case these constructions can be generalized to finitely many random variables by looking at the uniform distribution on $(0,1)^n$ instead of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? My guess would be that you are either criticizing the first paragraph or the longwindedness of the rest of it, but I am curious to hear your particular criticism, especially as it apparently does not pertain to any of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a random variable with uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

Prescribe $\Phi:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ by:$$u\mapsto\inf\{x\in\mathbb R\mid u\leq F(x)\}$$

Then it can be shown that:$$\Phi(u)\leq x\iff u\leq F(x)$$

So letting $U$ be a random variable with uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ we have:$$\Phi(U)\leq x\iff U\leq F(x)$$and consequently:$$F_{\Phi(U)}(x)=P(\Phi(u)\leq x)=P(U\leq F(x))=F(x)$$

This always works.

In the special case where $F$ has an inverse we find that $\Phi$ is actually that inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=g^{-1}(Y)$ where $Y$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and $g(\cdot)$ is strictly increasing (and hence invertible).

Then $$F_X(x)=P(X\le x)=P(g^{-1}(Y) \le x) = P(Y \le g(x))=g(x) $$

Comment: This looks  mathematically fine, but is there way to intuitively understand this?

Comment: Perhaps it's a little easier to think it the other way https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868400/showing-that-y-has-a-uniform-distribution-if-y-fx-where-f-is-the-cdf-of-contin

Comment: One intuitive way to think about the concept above (inverse transform sampling) is this: Visualize the graph of your CDF which has the range $(0,1)$. Imagine picking a point randomly in the range $(0,1)$ on the vertical axis, then going horizontally until you hit the CDF, then dropping to the horizontal axis, and picking where you landed to be your rv's realization. Think about doing this over and over. In the long run, think about the distribution of the realizations you will get.