# What is the intuitive explanation for the CDF of any random variable to follow uniform distribution (0,1)?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X$ is a continuously distributed random variable and $F$ is the c.d.f. of its distribution, then $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $(0,1).$

While i'm clear with the mathematical proof, I'm looking for an intuitive answer to this.

Comment: This must be a duplicate, but cannot find it

Comment: Please give a tiny bit of hint about what you don't find intuitive.  Are you comfortable with CDF's in general but uniform RVs somehow baffle you, or the opposite, or both?

Comment: This only applies to continuous cumulative distribution functions, i.e. for continuous random variables

Comment: What is the probability for an outcome to occur in an event whose probability is $y$?

Comment: It's really unclear what this is about. To ask for an intuitive explanation, it helps to give a clear statement of the mathematical fact you are interested in--the definition, formula, whatever, saying what all the parts of it are; explain the way in which you already understand it (in this case, what is the mathematical proof?), and _then_ ask for a more intuitive explanation. If you want to try this, use the "edit" link just below the question text to insert this information into the question; don't try to explain in comments.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - try https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868400/showing-that-y-has-a-uniform-distribution-if-y-fx-where-f-is-the-cdf-of-contin or some of those linked to it

Comment: @DavidK : The language in which the posting was initially expressed was not up to passable standards of precision for mathematicians or even for homework being graded. But I have edited to clarify what I think must have been the poster's intent.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, the language was so poorly organized that I completely missed the point. Now that you've helped OP out by fixing it, I think this is distinct from the linked question because this one asks for intuition rather than a proof. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are dealing with continuous random variables

- the CDF $F(X)$ is a continuous increasing function of $X$ where the probability that $F(X) \le p$  for $p \in (0,1)$ is the probability that $X \le q$ when $F(q)=p$, which is $p$
- so $F(X)$ has a uniform distribution on the unit interval, since the probability it is less than or equal to a given $p \in (0,1)$ is $p$

Comment: "Intuitive"? $ $