# Rigorous proof of CDF $F_X(X)$ is uniform

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be given.
It is well known that, for continuous random variable $X(\omega)$, with CDF $F(x)$, then $F(X(\omega))$ is a uniform random variable.
I want to look up a proof of this, and found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868400/showing-that-y-has-a-uniform-distribution-if-y-fx-where-f-is-the-cdf-of-contin).
I believe the highest voted answer by `JimmyK4542` to be flawed, in that, the answerer uses $F^{-1}$.
Let
$$
A =\{ \omega: F(X) \leq y \} \\
B =\{ \omega: X \leq F^{-1} (y) \}
$$
Then it would seem that
$$
\mathbb{P} (A)
=\mathbb{P} (B)
$$
but if $F'(\xi)=0$ for some $\xi$, $F^{-1}$ must not exist at $\xi$, by inverse function theorem, and $B$ is undefined.

So I tried the following proof, please check for me, and do tell me whether there are more concise ones.
As someone suggests in the comment, I try
$$
\tilde{A} =\{\omega: X \leq x_0\} \\
x_0 :=\inf\; \{\tilde{x}: F(\tilde{x}) \geq y\}
$$
I say that
$$
A =\tilde{A}
$$
Indeed, fix any $x \in A$, then $F(x) \leq y$.
For any $\tilde{x}$ so that $F(\tilde{x}) \geq y$, we have $F(\tilde{x}) \geq F(x)$, and, since $F$ is nondecreasing, $\tilde{x} \geq x$, and $x \in \tilde{A}$.

Conversely, fix any $x \in \tilde{A}$, so for any $F(\tilde{x}) \geq y$, we have $\tilde{x} \geq x$, and $F(\tilde{x}) \geq F(x)$ by monotonicity.
Prove by contradiction, assuming $F(x) >y$.
Let $\tilde{x}$ be chosen, such that $x-\tilde{x}>0$ be so small that $F(x) > F(\tilde{x}) >y$, which is possible by continuity.
This simply contradicts the previous statement.

Thus $A =\tilde{A}$ is true, and $\mathbb{P} (A) =\mathbb{P} (\tilde{A})$.

Next, I claim that $F (x_0) =y$.
Choose any $x >x_0$, but $x -x_0$ is so small that $F(x) \leq F(x_0) +\epsilon$, due to continuity.
Then there is a $z$ so that $x > z > x_0$, and $F(z) \geq y$, by the nature of inf.
So $F(x_0) +\epsilon \geq F(x) \geq F(z) \geq y$.

It remains to show $F(x_0) \leq y$.
Since any single point $x$ has probability measure 0, we can establish that $F$ is onto $(0,1)$.
Thus, there is some $z$ so that $F(z) =y$.
Now, $F(z) \geq y$ and so $x_0 \leq z$ by the definition of inf.
We have $F(x_0) \leq F(z) =y$.

The intended result is immediate by invoking the definition of CDF and expression of $\mathbb {P} (A)$.
Am I overthinking?
Are there more straightforward proofs?

Comment: This is known as the probability integral transform.

Answer (score 3):

So, I am not sure what you are exactly trying to prove, but I think that I can write something that might answer your question.

In general, we know that CDFS are [càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) functions, so that if $F$ is a CDF, then

- the left limits $\lim_{x\to t^-} F(x)$ always exist
- the right limits $\lim_{x\to t^+} F(x)$ always exist and equal $F(t)$

Since $F$ is (not strictly) increasing, this means that the function can have jump discontinuities at worst, and that if there is a jump at $x=t$, then $F(t)$ is equal to the limit from the right.

This means that we can uniquely define the "[quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_.28quantile_function.29)", which is written as $F^{-1}$, but it's not the usual inverse. It is the same as the inverse for strictly increasing $F$, but otherwise it is defined (as you have written above) as
$$F^{-1}(y)=\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}:F(x)\geq y\}.$$
The "continuous from the right" property ensures that this infimum works nicely.

Using this definition of $F^{-1}$, it holds that $A=B$.

Comment: I am trying to prove $Y=F(X)$ is a uniform r.v. in $(0,1)$

Comment: Right. As you mentioned, the answer in the other post gives a proof, but it relies on the fact that $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B)$, which seemed to be the source of your confusion. I've given details that should let you prove that statement.

Comment: In particular, your proof is not quite right -- in general, a CDF does not have to be surjective (only continuous random variables have surjective CDFs). For an example, consider a Bernoulli random variable. Its CDF is a step function.

Comment: Hi, I already assumed in the first line that $X$ is continuous.

Comment: Now I still think my proof is right, just it is a very verbose completion of your outline. Maybe there are simpler proofs though.