# Show that $ \int_\mathbb{R} 2F(x)dF(x)=1 $.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $F$ be Stieltjes measure function (nondecreasing and right continuous) and $\mu$ be corresponding measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{R})$.  Assume that $F: \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ is continuous. Show that
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} 2F(x)dF(x)=1
$$

---

I found that this question is a corollary of Durrett's textbook exercise 1.7.3:

> Let $F$ be continuous. Then
> $$
> \int_{(a,b]}2 F(y)dF(y)=F^2(b)-F^2(a)
> $$

However, the proof relies on the previous results:

> Let $F, G$ be Stieltjes measure functions and let $\mu, \nu$ be corresponding measures. Then $$\int_{(a,b]}F(y)dG(y)+\int_{(a,b]}G(y)dF(y)=F(b)G(b)-F(a)G(a)+\sum_{x\in (a,b]} \mu(\{x\})\nu(\{x\})$$

Can we prove our result without using this result?

If we just apply Durrett's result, then we take $a\to-\infty, b\to \infty$, we will prove our result.

Comment: Fixed.  should be $2x$

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, that is true because $F$ is actually cdf...

Comment: The question should state that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the continuity of $F$, let $X$ be a random variable with distribution function $F$. Then $\int F(x)\,dF(x) = \mathbb E[F(X)]$. Since $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, it follows $\mathbb E[F(X)] = \frac{1}{2}$, which solves the problem.

Comment: You may note that $F(X) \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$ when $F$ is a continuous CDF, and it does not necessarily hold for right continuous CDF (@Hermi).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @BBBBBB Why $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$?

Comment: See this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868400/showing-that-y-has-a-uniform-distribution-if-y-fx-where-f-is-the-cdf-of-contin

Comment: @BBBBBB F is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ or $[0,1]$?

Comment: $[0,1]$, but it doesn't really matter since the probability of attaining any given point is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int udv = uv - \int vdu$$

Claim:

$$\int F(x) dF(x) = F^2(b) - F^2(a) - \int F(x)dF(x)$$

Proof:

Since this is integral is Riemann integrable, we have:
$$g([a,b]) = \int_{[a,b]} F(x)dF(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n-1} F(a_i) (F(a_{i+1}) - F(a_i))$$
$$ = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n-1} F(a_i) (F(a_{i+1}) - F(a_i)) - F^2(a_{i+1}) + F^2(a_i) + F^2(a_{i+1}) - F^2(a_i)$$
$$ = F^2(b) - F^2(a) + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n-1} F(a_i) (F(a_{i+1}) - F(a_i)) - F^2(a_{i+1}) + F^2(a_i)$$
$$ = F^2(b) - F^2(a) + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n-1} F(a_i) F(a_{i+1}) - F^2(a_{i+1})$$
$$ = F^2(b) - F^2(a) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n-1}  F(a_{i+1})(F(a_{i+1}) - F(a_i))$$
$$ = F^2(b) - F^2(a) - \int F(x) dF(x)$$

Rest follows since,
$$\int F(x) dF(x) = \frac{1}{2} (F^2(b) - F^2(a))$$

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask if we can apply the first integration by parts in measure theory? I am confused that in Durrett's textbook, exercise 1.7.3 is actually the IBP.

Comment: Here definition of $F$ is same as continuous CDF. Is your $dF(x)=F'(x)d\mu$ true for CDF?

Comment: Measure for a CDF $F(x)$ is actually: $F'(x) dx$ since $\mu([a,b]) = F(b) - F(a) = F'(x) (b-a)$ by mean value theorem. So $dF(x) = F'(x) dx$. Since $F'(x) > 0$, this is valid measure. Infact you can define measure by $\mu([a,b]) = \int_{[a,b]} f(x) dx$ where $f(x)>0$. Here we are indirectly saying a CDF is monotonic and has positive derivative and can act as $f(x) = F'(x)$. But $f(x) = F'(x)$ is density function actually. But density function need not exist in general i.e., derivative $F'(x)$ need not exist for $F(x)$. So saying $dF(x) = F'(x) dx$ is true only when derivative exist.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look.